# When i run my code i get NoClassDefFoundError 2 packages

Tags: java

Im trying to get an ai chat into a gui sp i can chat with it there instead of just in the console. But when i have the 2 packages and try to run them i get error in my code, but i dont see any problems in the code itself

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/295968024165351426/416204412307111936/unknown.png since i theres no clear error in my code, im not sure what code to post here. so heres a image of line 34-35

Comment: Just since i cant post all of my code i pasted it into pastebin https://pastebin.com/P4Jhdsjh

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` occur only when the class file found at compile time and not found in run time so please check classpath whether the class file is present.